# How can I document a method which throws a generic exception in C#?

Tags: c#, exception, documentation

I have a method which throws a generic exception and I would like to document it, however I cannot figure out how to write a valid xml doc.

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Throws any exception.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TException">Type of the exception to throw </typeparam>
        /// <exception cref="TException"> Thrown when whatever.... </exception>
        public static void Throw<TException>() where TException : Exception
        {
            throw (TException)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TException));
        }
```

The above gives the below error:

> XML comment has a csref attribute that refers to a type parameter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Referring to a generic type of a generic type in C# XML documentation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684982/referring-to-a-generic-type-of-a-generic-type-in-c-sharp-xml-documentation)

Comment: Thanks Hugo, but unfortunately that does not apply to this question. I have no problem documenting a method which say has an IList<string> as an argument. The question asked here is specifically about generic exceptions. Please provide an example if you think the other question answers this one and I will close this question.

Comment: @MaYaN your question is very hard to understand, would you like to explain your problem a little bit more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I figured it out using:

```
/// <summary>
/// Throws any exception.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TException">Type of the exception to throw </typeparam>
/// <exception>Thrown when
///     <cref>TException</cref> whatever...
/// </exception>    
public static void Throw<TException>() where TException : Exception
{
    throw (TException)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TException));
}
```